# Execute multiple root shell commands in Android

Tags: android, root

I'm developing an application that execute multiple shell command in different time.
I'm using the following method:

```
public void RunAsRoot(String[] cmds){
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());            
        for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
                os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");
        }           
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");  
        os.flush();
}
```

This method works fine but it always open a new shell every time I need to call it, so that it display the annoying toast "Application has been granted for root permission". 
I think this is becouse it always open and close a new shell with SU access. My question is: is there any way to leave a SU shell always open so that I can run my commands when needed without receive the SU toast?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser or https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools

Comment: Im actually using libsuperuser from chainfire, but Shell.SU.run always open a new shell!

Answer (score 0):

So this might be a bit late, but in case you are still searching for a solution: Just declare

```
private Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

globally in your class. This should fit your needs.
You can actually spawn the process in `onResume()` and `destroy()` it again in `onPause()`.

```
@Override  
onResume() {
  if(//check for root) {
     try { 
         this.p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 
         } 
     catch(IOException e) { 
         // Exception handling goes here 
         }
     }
  //set up everything else
}

@Override  
onPause() {
  this.p.destroy();
}
```

BTW: I see a serious memory leak in the above method: You open a variety of SU processes but never `destroy()` them again. Depending on how often you call this method there will be more and more SU processes lying around in RAM until your app is closed.

So

`public void runAsRoot(String[] cmds){
        try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
        // Exception handling goes here
        }
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

        for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
                os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");
        }

        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        p.destroy();
}`

would be good here. I'm also asking myself if you can compile your approach. Usually `Runtime.getRuntime().exec();` has to be surrounded by try/catch.